# Attaching image to a Canvas and render it at the same size as the Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to put a canvas above a character in my game in order to show some information about its animation / health, etc. in order to debug it.
I'm doing all this by code.

Therefore I'm first adding a GameObject to the Character.
Then I add a Canvas to this GameObject. 
This works fine.

Then I add a "Panel" to this GameObject and put an image into it. I want to use this image as the background of the text that will be displayed.

I seem to be unable to make the Panel of such a size that it would fit perfectly in the Canvas GameObject.

Same goes for the text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

private void pCreateCanvas()
    {
        GameObject nCanvasGO = new GameObject("CanvasContainer");
        nCanvasGO.transform.SetParent(_ThisCharacter.transform); //parent the gameobject to the character

```
    Canvas nCanvas = nCanvasGO.AddComponent<Canvas>();//Adding a canvas to a Gameobject will automatically change the Transform to a RectTransform
    nCanvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
    nCanvasGO.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
    nCanvasGO.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    //CanvasContainer's RectTransform
    RectTransform rtCanvasGO = nCanvasGO.GetComponent<RectTransform>();// Adding a canvas to a Gameobject will automatically change the Transform to a RectTransform
    rtCanvasGO.localScale = new Vector3(0.01f, 0.01f, 1f); //scale it down so that it fits in the scene
    rtCanvasGO.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);//rotate it so that it faces me
    rtCanvasGO.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 2, 0); //y=2 m (place the canvas game object 2 metres of the character's feet = over it's head)
    rtCanvasGO.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtCanvasGO.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtCanvasGO.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100, 10);

    GameObject nPanelGO = new GameObject("Panel");
    nPanelGO.transform.SetParent(nCanvasGO.transform, false);//parent it to the nCanvasGO
    nPanelGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();//wird benötigt, bisher ist es nur ein Transform, kein RectTransform (das Anchor usw. hat)
    nPanelGO.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
    //PanelContainer's RectTransform
    RectTransform rtPanelGO = nPanelGO.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rtPanelGO.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    rtPanelGO.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtPanelGO.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    rtPanelGO.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtPanelGO.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    rtPanelGO.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100, 10);

    Image nImage = nPanelGO.AddComponent<Image>();
    nImage.color = Color.red;

    GameObject nTextGO = new GameObject("TextHolder");
    nTextGO.transform.SetParent(nPanelGO.transform, false);//make it a child of its own
    _text = nTextGO.AddComponent<Text>();

    Font ArialFont = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf");
    _text.font = ArialFont;
    _text.material = ArialFont.material;

    //Text's RectTransform
    RectTransform rtText = _text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    //rtText.localPosition =  Not sure what to do here 
    rtText.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtText.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtText.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rtText.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    rtText.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100, 10);
    rtText.localPosition = new Vector3(-50, 0, 0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create all the structure beforehand using the editor and add custom script to handle all staff relative to displaying visual information you want, save as a prefab, your character can then instantiate this prefab and use its API to visualize all the info you need without worrying about how it will do it (incapsulate "the how" inside your data visualization prefab).

Comment: You should be able to set `anchorMin` to `Vector.zero` and `anchorMax` to `Vector.one` and then leave `localPosition` as `Vector3.zero`.

Comment: @misher I don't want to use a prefab, I feel more "safe" with script.

Comment: @tmighty you will be much more safe if you apply _solid_ principles, and unity editor gives you also useful tools you probably should use, otherwise, you lose the benefit of having an engine

Comment: @Foggzie I tried that, but it didn't change the size of the red image. Would you mind stating a full code (as an answer) so that I can test it?

Comment: @Foggzie I understand your code, and when I set these values at runtime by changing the panel's RectTransform Left, Top, Right, Bottom to 0, it looks perfectly fine. However, settings these Vector.zero by code seems to have no effect. Any other idea why this might fail?

Comment: You may also simplify your code by grabbing the reference to panel rect transform when it is created:RectTransform rtPanelGO  =  nPanelGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();

Comment: @misher Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
 rtPanelGO.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
 rtPanelGO.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
```

try

```
 rtPanelGO.offsetMin= new Vector2(0, 0);
 rtPanelGO.offsetMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

UPDATE:
The key is to work with recttransform, of course, bare in mind that some changes you make to it can have no effect on the frame you create it. You may try to wait for 1 frame and then apply all changes to the panel when the canvas and all gameobjects are effectively added to the scene. Use coroutine, for example.

Please refer to https://forum.unity.com/threads/setting-top-and-bottom-on-a-recttransform.265415 on the unity's forum for more info about setting top and bottom offsets.

UPDATE2:
Talke a look at this method also:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge.html

Comment: Works so good, thank you so much!! You don't know how many hours I've tried to do that today.